# How can I redirect "localhost" to another local IP?

Tags: ip-address, redirection, localhost

This is my situation:

Two computer under the same router, 192.168.1.101 and 192.168.1.102

This is what I like to do: On 192.168.1.101, while accessing port 22 with localhost, it directs the traffic to 192.168.1.102 port 22.

In another word, I would like to forward whatever traffic from localhost to another local IP.

Is there any solution for what I need?

Comment: It might help to know what you are trying to achieve, knowing your OS would help, too.

Comment: netcat ... but you'd have to disable ssh on 1.101.  What *ARE* you trying to do?

Comment: You're misusing the term localhost. Sounds like you think it's the locally assigned internet accessible IP address. It isn't. The loopback network (127.0.0.0) which will contain your localhost (127.0.0.1) is used for all IP communications that are supposed to happen within that box you call a computer. This is one of those questions, which if you have to ask it, you don't understand enough to be messing around with it.

Answer (score 8):

If you’re on Windows, you can use the command:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=192.168.1.101 listenport=21 connectaddress=192.168.1.102 connectport=21
```

Replace:

- `21` with the port you want to forward,
- `192.168.1.101` with your ip,
- `192.168.1.102` with the destination ip.

Answer (score 5):

Don't redefine the meaning of localhost. You'll break things in surprising ways.

Instead, look at the `-L` and `-R` options in `ssh(1)`.  They make it easy to redirect a port on the local machine to the IP address and port of a remote machine. Plus the tunnel is secured by SSH.

Note that these tunnels are not necessarily specific to ssh/shell traffic. It can be for arbitrary traffic.

Comment: But this means that I will need an SSH client on the device I'm going to connect to host with :(

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if that is a smart thing to do. A lot of services intended to run on the local machine use either `127.0.0.1` (which would be no problem with your change) or `localhost` (in which case your change would mess things up) to connect to other services on the same machine. And a lot of other packages comes configured this way.

If the purpose is to have the same name to connect crosswise, regardless on which machine you are, I'd rather recommend to use a different name for this. Instead of "localhost" you could e.g. use "crosshost" - and with that follow the hints given by Indrek: Check for your `hosts` file (on Linux/Unix and probably also Mac it is `/etc/hosts`, on Windows it is `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` (without extension -- so take care here, Windows usually already has some other `hosts.*` file in that directory). Do **NOT** comment out the `127.0.0.1 localhost` line, nor modify it -- leave it as is. Just add a line

```
192.168.1.101 crosshost
```

on the 192.168.1.102 machine, and similarly with the other address on the other machine. Now you can e.g. `ssh crosshost` to connect to one machine from the other, or copy files over with `scp filename.ext crosshost:/path/to/put`, or whatever you intended.