# Chrome on Android ignores host file

Tags: google-chrome, android, localhost

I need to access my lamp server from my Android phone. The problem is I need to access it using "localhost" URL not the IP address. I have rooted my phone to be able to edit the HOSTS file. I have done it successfully. I have tested by PING-ing localhost. It works fine in LanDroid and also when I enter http://localhost into default Android browser works, but Chrome still shows "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". I have also try to reboot my device several times with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: EDIT: when I add some other address into hosts it works-I have added 192.168.1.12 localhostt (with double T) and it works, but i would like to use localhost.

Comment: Local host is the Android. You cannot use `localhost` to access a different machine.

Comment: @DavidPostill do you have any link with more info? When it works with PING (using LanDroid app) and also in Android Browser I would expect it to work in Chrome too.

Comment: `ping localhost` is **pinging yourself**. If your lamp server is on a different machine you cannot browse to it using `localhost`

Comment: but when I used `ping` in LanDroid it showed me the IP of my server (different machine). And the same works on Browser app.

Comment: Where is your lamp server located?

Comment: [127.0.0.1 – What Are its Uses and Why is it Important?](http://www.tech-faq.com/127-0-0-1.html)

Comment: On my Ubuntu machine located on the same network as my Android phone. I can access it using `192.168.1.12` address but I would prefere to access it using `localhost` if possible.

Comment: You can't do that. `localhost` is **by definition** `127.0.0.1`. You cannot redefine it.

Comment: Well you can, but then all sorts of things can break as you have found out.

Comment: OK. I got it. Nothing have braked down. Everything is ok just Chrome ignores is but I guess, there is not much I can do about it.

Comment: "When tested Chrome did not use the hosts file in any operating system" http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Comment: [How can I redirect "localhost" to another local IP?](http://superuser.com/q/443691) says "Don't do it"

Comment: You are right. I have added another alias. Now I am able to access my localhost from all devices using `local` (http://local/). Thanks for your time.

Comment: Great!. Now please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) ;)

Answer (score -1):

It seams like redirecting `localhost` to other machine is not recommended. I have chosen different approach. I am using alias (`http://local/`) instead. Now I am able to access my localhost from all my devices (with edited `hosts` file) using `http://local/` url.